# How to load angular translation after some event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have a TranslationService that is called after a login event, in this service I want to inizialize the $translateProvider.translation but this object seems not accessibile outside app.config(...). In the service I want to replace the previous translation.
Here some code:

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {        
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'i18n/',
            suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('it');
}]);
```

While in my TranslateService I need something like

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .factory('TranslateService', ['$translate', $translateProvider, function($translate, $translateProvider) {
        $mydata = { "LABEL": "Label" };
        $translateProvider.translations('it', mydata); // injection problem
        $translate.somethingLike_getProvider().translations('it', mydata); // doesn't exist
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to store [`$translateProvider`](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Getting-Started#configuring-translateprovider) in a variable that can be accessed later:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
var provider = null;

app.config(function($translateProvider) {
  provider = $translateProvider;
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.factory('inlineLoaderFactory', function($q) {
  return function(options) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(options[options.key]);
    return deferred.promise;
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, $translate) {
  $scope.override = function() {
    provider.useLoader('inlineLoaderFactory', {
      en: {
        TITLE: 'Hello My Friend',
        FOO: 'TLDR',
        CUSTOM: 'New Key'
      }
    });
    $translate.refresh();
  };
});
```

When a change to translations is required we tell `$translateProvider` to use `inlineLoaderFactory` [translation loader service](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading#using-custom-loader-service). The `inlineLoaderFactory` merely uses options as new translation data.